Teams deep link not opening the specific chat
I'm using teams deep link to open Teams desktop app group chat conversations from my angular app. When I click on the link, it opens teams app but it doesn't navigate to the chat which I mentioned in the deep link. The teams app shows the previous chat which I have opened already.
HTML:
<a mat-raised-button class="icon-chat" href="msteams:/l/chat19:6f0824e40c69485ba6ce9521e6ea7ab6@thread.v2/conversations">Click here</a>

Teams (New) Version: 24137.2216.2931.2440

The deep-link url provided in the description seems to be missing a "/" after chat. Could you please check that? Ex: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/19:6f0824e40c69485ba6ce9521e6ea7ab6@thread.v2/conversations

@Prasad-MSFT Dam!! My oversight, thanks for the help

The correct deep link url should be as below:
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/19:6f0824e40c69485ba6ce9521e6ea7ab6@thread.v2/conversations

...and msteams:/l/chat/19:6f0824e40c69485ba6ce9521e6ea7ab6@thread.v2/conversations for opening chat directly with teams desktop client (link in question lacks the slash)
